# $A\circ A^{-1}\geq I$, $A^{1/2}\circ B^{1/2}\leq I$.

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

> Let $A=(a_{ij})$, $B=(b_{ij})$ be two positive definite matrix. Define
> $$A\circ B=(a_{ij}b_{ij}).$$
> It is easy to verify that $A\circ B$ is positive definite.
> (1) But is the following right? $A\circ A^{-1}\geq I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix, that is, $A\circ A^{-1}-I$ is non-negative definite.
> (2) Also, If the diagnoal entries of $A,B$ is $1$, can we show $A^{1/2}\circ B^{1/2}\leq I$?

Some computations indicates (1) and (2) are right. But it seems that $A=C^T C$ for invertible $C$ is intricate.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the symbol "$\circ$" means Hadamard product.

The answer to your first question is affirmative. It is part of theorem 7.7.9(c) on p.475 of the first edition of Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis*. (I think this is also covered in the second edition, but the theorem and page numbers have probably changed drastically in the new edition.)

Comment: Is there any elementary proof of $A\circ A^{-1}\geq I$?

Comment: $A^{1/2}\circ B^{1/2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}I$!

Comment: @xldd You are right. I'll delete the mistaken part.